# XML request not working

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

I found this tutorial at W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_xml

I copied the whole JavaScript code and created an XML file myself with the tags, but when I press the button, nothing happens. Interestingly once I remove one of the `<CD>` tags and just leave one, it works. Anybody care to explain what exactly am I doing wrong?

In my cd_catalog.xml I have

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<CD>
    <ARTIST>Artist01</ARTIST>
    <TITLE>Title01</TITLE>
</CD>
<CD>
    <ARTIST>Artist02</ARTIST>
    <TITLE>Title02</TITLE>
</CD>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is an invalid xml file.
An xml file must have a single root node, when you removed a CD node it became valid because it had 1 top level node.
You can wrap those tags in a node to make the file valid xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<CDS>
    <CD>
        <ARTIST>Artist01</ARTIST>
        <TITLE>Title01</TITLE>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <ARTIST>Artist02</ARTIST>
        <TITLE>Title02</TITLE>
    </CD>
</CDS>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, didnt know that there has to be a parent node.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid XML, you can get the specific xml file that is in use for your example from here - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml. 
And next time you can easily validate your xml file by using some free xml validation online from google searce i.e http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```